# C#: Array.Sort method for double?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have an array ( double ) : ox_test with a known number of elements.

when I code :

```
Array.Sort(ox_test);
```

and then, just to see if the array it's sorted :

```
for (int y = 1; y <= ox_test.Length; y++)
     MessageBox.Show(".x: " + ox_test[y]);
```

.. I get ... 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ( if the number of elements was 5 ). Please help, thank you!

So i modified the both for loops:

```
for (int y = 0; y < ox_test.Length; y++)
    MessageBox.Show(".x: " + ox_test[y]);
    // HERE  i get the values not sorted but != 0

Array.Sort(ox_test);

for (int y = 0; y < ox_test.Length; y++)
    MessageBox.Show(".x s: " + ox_test[y]);
    // HERE i get only 0 values
```

Comment: Are you sure you've initialized your array of doubles to contain the data that you need?

Comment: what values does ox_test contain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// sort double array
double[] doubleArray = new double[5] { 8.1, 10.2, 2.5, 6.7, 3.3 };
Array.Sort(doubleArray);
// write array
foreach (double d in doubleArray) Console.Write(d + " ");  // output: 2.5 3.3 6.7 8.1 10.2
```

Answer (score 1):

You should start from 0 instead of 1.

```
for (int y = 0; y < ox_test.Length; y++)
    MessageBox.Show(".x: " + ox_test[y]);
```

Also, please be sure of initialization of `ox_test` array.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code:

```
Array.Sort(ox_test);

foreach (double i in ox_test)
{
    Console.Write(i + " ");
}
```